# Blackberry - how to read SMS and bookmarks?

Tags: blackberry, integration, sms, bookmarks

I  wanted to do a application which will read bookmarks & SMS

1. Is there a way to read SMS from Inbox/Outbox/Sent folders for blackberry devices? I have read many  forum post replying that it is not possible to read SMS, still i wanted to know any possibilities through which i can achieve?
2. Is there is any way to read saved bookmarks using blackberry APIs?

any solution regarding this will be very helpful.

Comment: voted to delete my "answer" seeing you have now accepted 78% of answers - much better - it would still be helpful to ask a question with a specific problem or question rather than such a broad open ended question